# HorizontalScrollView inside TabHost causes problems on orientation switch

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TabActivity with the TabHost's TabWidget inside a HorizontalScrollView.  I am trying to programmatically select a tab when the orientation changes, so that when the user changes from portrait to landscape, for example, the active tab remains the same.

What happens is that when the first tab is the active tab (selected and focused) when I change orientation, the second tab becomes the active tab when my Activity starts back up.  If the second through the nth tab is the active tab when the orientation changes, that tab correctly becomes the active tab; the issue happens only for the first tab.

When the Activity pauses I save the active tab's tag in the system shared preferences, and when the Activity starts I grab the tag from the preferences in order to use `setCurrentTabByTag(string)` on the TabHost.  The issue happens whether I save/restore the tab by index or by tag.  The issue also happens whether I use onStop/onStart or onPause/onResume for saving and restoring the active tab, respectively.

This is not a problem if the TabWidget is not inside a HorizontalScrollView, but not having the HorizontalScrollView is not an option (even though my code example only shows 4 tabs.)

Also, my example shows that I programmatically create the tabs because that is how I need to do it in my app; my tabs are dynamic.

My question is this: How can I get the selected tab to remain the same when I change orientation, even for the first tab?  Please keep in mind that I must create the tabs programmatically, and I must have the TabWidget in a HorizontalScrollView.

Here is my layout main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And here is my TabActivity:

```
public class RestoreSelectedTabTestActivity extends TabActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_TAB_PREFERENCE_KEY = "selectedTabPref";
    private static final String TAG = "RestoreTabTest";

    private Context mApp;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mApp = getApplicationContext();
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mApp);

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.clearAllTabs();

        addTab(1);
        addTab(2);
        addTab(3);
        addTab(4);

        // restore tab selection
        String selectedTabTag = mPrefs.getString(
                SELECTED_TAB_PREFERENCE_KEY, "");
        Log.v(TAG, "restoring tab pref " + selectedTabTag);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(selectedTabTag);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // save tab selection
        String selectedTabTag = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(SELECTED_TAB_PREFERENCE_KEY, selectedTabTag);
        editor.commit();
        Log.v(TAG, "saved tab pref " + selectedTabTag);
    };

    private void addTab(final int tabId) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + tabId);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab " + tabId);
        tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
               Log.v(TAG, "createTabContent " + tag);
                TextView textView = new TextView(mApp);
                textView.setText("This is Tab #" + tabId);

                return textView;
            }
        });
        Log.v(TAG, "addTab " + tabSpec.getTag());
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        // required for setting focus programmatically
        View tab = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(
                mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount() - 1);
        tab.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
}
```

Edit: here is the LogCat output when switching orientation with the first tab selected:

```
addTab tab1
createTabContent tab1
addTab tab2
addTab tab3
addTab tab4
restoring tab pref tab1
createTabContent tab2
```

Where does the `createTabContent tab2` output on the last line come from?

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is programmatically selecting a tab when the orientation changes,  mandatory in your application? Please try by avoiding that. Also you may add the tabs to TabHost in the onCreate.

Comment: It's _mandatory_ from a user experience perspective.  If there are 10 tabs, for instance, and the user is on the 9th tab when they switch orientation, I want the 9th tab to be their active tab after the switch, not the first tab.  This works for the 2nd to the nth tab, just not the 1st tab for some reason.  As far as which event I use, I understand I can use onCreate, even onResume for that matter; the problem is programmatically selecting the 1st tab.

Comment: I took a peek through the Android source code for TabHost to see what may be happening, but I couldn't find anything that jumped out at me.  I did notice, however, that calling setCurrentTab() and focusCurrentTab() after setCurrentTabByTag() was redundant, so I edited my post to reflect that.